# C++: Allowing Access to Protected Members of Class and not Private Members

Tags: c++, class

I know you can do this with inheritance, but you're meant to use inheritance for except for 'is a' circumstances. I also know there are friends, but they allow access to private members as well.

Is there any way of doing this (Allowing Access to Protected Members of Class and not Private Members)?

To reword the question, I have class 1 and class 2. I want class two to have access to class 1's protected and public members, but not it's private members. How would I do this?

Comment: What is this `this` you refer in `Is there any way of doing this?`

Comment: I should have been more clear. I am referring to the question: "Allowing Access to Protected Members of Class and not Private Members"

Comment: As for allowing access to who, I am referring to the first class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not elegant, but this might work for you:

```
class B;

class A {
protected:
    int x;
private:
    int y;
};

class A_wrapper : public A {
    friend B;
};


class B {
public:
    A_wrapper a;
    int foo() {
        a.x;   // Ok
        a.y;   // Compiler error!
    }
};
```

Comment: It's indeed tricky to get something clean. `protected` works on members of the base class subobject, but not on members of other objects of the same type. (I.e. only via `this`)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth but would you say it is a good idea to do this? Not your implementation but the general idea.

Comment: This looks like the cleanest and simplest way of doing it, so I'll accept it though from some of the comments around I think I might try to get this working by moving some other the variables so I don't have to.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I guess it depends on the situation.  If one needs to do this, it's probably indicative that a redesign is required (although one doesn't always have that luxury!).

Comment: Just because a language prevents you from doing something does not mean it's the design problem. It may as well be a language limitation. For example, a 'friend' is all-or-nothing. You cannot give permission to access only a portion of your private/protected contents. Yes, you can walkaround this, e.g. by splitting a class into two or more pieces. It may seem a "cleaner" way from the engineering point of view, but this gives a lot of boilerplate code. And if you have too much of boilerplate, then it becomes hard to use, no matter how correct it seems from the engineering standpoint.

Comment: @CygnusX1 - Five years on, I definitely agree with that sentiment (i.e. language limitations != design problem), in general :)  That said, even now I'd probably still suggest that the OP is a bit of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) without further context.

Answer (score 2):

Long ago, on this very website, I presented a scheme using a `Key`. The idea is that the main class documents which parts of the interface are accessible publicly and which necessitates a key, and then friendship to the key is granted to those who need it.

```
class Key { friend class Stranger; Key() {} ~Key() {} };

class Item {
public:
    void everyone();

    void restricted(Key);
private:
};
```

Now, only `Stranger` may use the `restricted` method, as is demonstrated here:

```
class Stranger {
public:
    void test(Item& i) {
        Key k;
        i.restricted(k);
    }

    Key key() { return Key(); }

    Key _key;
};

class Other {
    void test(Item& i) {
        Stranger s;
        i.restricted(s.key()); // error: ‘Key::~Key()’ is private
                               // error: within this context
    }

    void test2(Item& i) {
        Stranger s;
        i.restricted(s._key); // error: ‘Key::~Key()’ is private
                              // error: within this context
                              // error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void Item::restricted(Key)’
    }
};
```

It is a very simple scheme which allows a much finer grained approach that full friendship.

Answer (score 1):

Oli's provided a closer solution (+1), but you could also approach it using a selective friend:

```
#include <iostream>

class t_thing;

class t_elsewhere {
public:
    void print(const t_thing& thing);
};

class t_thing {
public:
    class t_selective_friend {
        static int Prot(const t_thing& thing) {
            return thing.prot;
        }

        friend class t_elsewhere;
    };
public:
    int publ;
protected:
    int prot;
protected:
    int priv;
};

void t_elsewhere::print(const t_thing& thing) {
    std::cout << t_thing::t_selective_friend::Prot(thing) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    t_thing thing;

    thing.publ; /* << ok */
    thing.prot; /* << error */
    thing.priv; /* << error */
    t_elsewhere().print(thing); /* << ok */
    return 0;
}
```

Sometimes that verbosity/control is good…